# Using 2 maps on the same source?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have 2 maps that I want to throw into the same source. But it seems one source overrides the second source even though I am targeting different fields.

```
  public class FormViewModel 
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public string SomeField {get; set;}
        // I have many more
    }

List<Items> items = Service.GetItems();

FormViewModel viewModel = new FormViewModel()
 {
      Items = Mapper.Map<List<Items>, List<SelectListItem>>(courses);         
 };

var fields = Service.GetFields();
viewModel = Mapper.Map<Fields, FormViewModel>(fields);
```

So now when I do the second map. It will wipe out my first map. How can I stop this?

Edit

I guess I can see why it is happening. I thought it was just filling in those the fields but now I am looking at it and seeing that it is return a new FormViewModel.

I guess I can rearrange my code so that I first do the last map first then add my other map after.

```
   List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM> vm = Mapper.Map<List<CalendarAppointment>, List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM>>(taskReminders.Select(x => x.CalendarAppointment).ToList());
        Mapper.Map<List<AppointmentReminder>, List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM>>(taskReminders, vm);
```

Separately they work. But together the first result gets wiped out by the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the output of the first mapping into the second mapping so it doesn't create a new one...

```
viewModel = Mapper.Map<Fields, FormViewModel>(fields, viewModel);
```

Comment: I am having trouble with lists on this one. Still keeps wiping out my old one - see edit

Comment: If I understand correctly, both of your sources have a list, and you want the list from the first one, but the second one is overwriting that with an empty list.  If this is the case, just "Ignore" the list when you CreateMap for the second one.

Comment: Well I have a list that has many properties for reasons I had to break it up into 2 maps to map all the properties. So the first map will fill x properties for everything in the list collection. Then the 2nd map will go and finish the job.